# In C#, what's the preferred definition of a form in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

In an application that has a `formMain` and some other forms (`formAccount`, `formPerson`, etc);

(1) Defining separate forms as separate classes and creating (instantiating) them whenever needed:

```
class FormAccount : Form {
    public FormAccount(...) {
        ...
    }
}

class FormMain : Form {
    public FormMain(...) {
        ...
    }
}

class Program {
    FormMain formMain = new FormMain();

    static void SomeFoo() {
        ...
        FormAccount formAccount = new FormAccount();
        ...
    }

    static int Main(string[] argv) {
        ...
        Application.Run(formMain);
        return (0);
    }    
}
```

or

(2) Defining each form with in one class and using `formXxxx.Show()` when needed.

```
class Program {
    Form formMain = new Form();
    Form formAccount = new Form();

    static int Main(string[] argv) {
        ...
        Application.Run(formMain);
        return (0);
    }    
}
```

The first one seems memory friendly, for the forms that are closed from time to time will free the heap memory. Whereas, some forms are regularly opened & closed and it seems to me that these forms are better to stay alive in the memory.

What is the preference of defining these forms?

Comment: There are two basic ways to learn Winforms programming: trial&error or reading books/tutorials.  Since you want to do this the trial way, you need to use approach #2 first.  Lots of error, you'll learn what ObjectDisposedException means and that's pretty important.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think I know what you mean but for the latter case, forms other than the `formMain` will not be closed / terminated (close button will be disabled). One button click on `formMain` will switch the `Visible` attribute to `true` for `formAccount` and another button on `formAccount` will switch the `Visible` attribute to `false`. Do you think I still might get an ObjectDisposedException in that case?

Comment: Defining a class per form is who the VS Designer works and in addition it separates concerns (see "S" of the SOLID principals). I would go for this as you have tool-support and you can place the form-specific code in its class separated from other forms code.

Comment: Forms are just classes. Follow the same practices you would for any disposable resource.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, there is no guideline for forms. However, if you use an IDE like Visual Studio, they do exist. The Visual Studio Designer requires that a form to be edited must be the first class of a file, and only the first one can be visually edited.